# To get product collections by some range of ids in magento

Tags: php, price, product-collection

I want to update all product price by specific percentage from current price.I got the following line of code update price by percentage wise

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('price');
 foreach ($products as $product) {

 $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.03);
 $product->save();
 echo $product->getId()."updated Sucess";
 }
```

Its working well. But it will take **so much time to complete** the above process because we have a lot of products in our store. Some times it will return **time out error** too. So i want to perform this above operation by **split those product collections** like if we have **1000 products**, do this operation by like below

```
Collect 1st 100 products from product collections
Update price of those products
Then collect next 100 products
Update price of those products
```

Anybody have an idea to get product collections by some range of ids?

**EDIT:**

The below accepted answers are the solution of my exact problem. If you want the solution of "**To get product collections by some range of ids in magento**" this question, please check [this post](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/to-get-product-collections-by-range-of-ids-in-magento/)

or refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929545/to-get-product-collections-by-some-range-of-ids-in-magento)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product `save` is really time consuming. And doing it for a lot of products will take a while. Since you need to update just the price you can make use of the `updateAttribtues` option.
So your code can become:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price');
 foreach ($products as $product) {
     $newPrice = $product->getPrice() * 1.03;
     Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
         array($product->getId()),
         array('price'=>$newPrice), 
         0
     );
    echo $product->getId()."updated Sucess";
 }
```

This is the 'code' option. It is faster than what you are doing right now.
If it still is not fast enough try the direct sql approach proposed by @FabianBlechschmidt. That's the fastest, but backup your db first.

Comment: Above coding of you working well. But i want to add one more condition to update price. that is,where store_id=5. In this situation, can't i update products?

Comment: Just change the last parameter of `updateAttribues` from `0` to `5`.

Comment: in catalog_product_entity_decimal this table, there is no row with store_id=5. because, i didn't set product price by store wise.

Comment: it's not important. Using `updateAttributes` should insert the row if it doesn't exist. But in case I'm wrong, backup your db.

Comment: yeah. Its working... Thank you yar! But in direct sql, I can't able to update due to default store id only exist on  that table. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## CLI

Run this script from the CLI, then there should be no timeout problem.

## DATABASE

The alternative is to write directly into the database. But you should really know, what you are doing here.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` cped 
  SET `value` = `value` * 1.03
  WHERE cped.entity_id IN ($listOfIds) 
      AND attribute_id = 
         (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'price' 
           AND entity_type_id = 
             (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type 
              WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
        )
```

Comment: shall i set price on specific store by this direct sql query?

Comment: okay. I got, how to set store condition. here $listOfIds means what? list of all product ids? @FabianBlechschmidt

Comment: yes, these are product IDs and everything is updated related to the product. You can set/update/filter by the `store_id` as well.

Comment: I have 4 stores in my single magento installation. i want to update the price of the store which id is 5. But in      'catalog_product_entity_decimal'  table, there is no row with store_id=5. if i edit price manually at backend, now only, i got the row with store_id=5. how can i update price to store_id=5?

Comment: You can't set the price on store level normally. Either they are global or on website scope, but I'm not sure how price scope is saved to the databse.